# Hi, I have this error require(F:\xampp\htdocs\Neitland\storage\proxies\__CG__AppEntitiesVilless.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine

I have this error (require(F:\xampp\htdocs\Neitland\storage\proxies__CG__AppEntitiesVilles.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory) every time I make a request to retrieve data from a table that is not even linked to the Villes.php entity. I use the Laravel-Doctrine ORM.
Here is the entity Villes.php

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity()
* @ORM\Table(name="villes")
*/

class Ville
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new Carbon();
    }

    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer",options={"unsigned"=true})
    */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=false)
     */
    private $libelle;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entities\Annonce", mappedBy="ville")
    */
    private $annonces;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entities\AgentImmobilier", mappedBy="ville")
    */
    private $agents;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entities\Notaire", mappedBy="ville")
    */
    private $notaires;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entities\Geometre", mappedBy="ville")
    */
    private $geometres;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="datetime",nullable=false)
    */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
    * Get the value of id
    */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
    * Set the value of id
    *
    * @return  self
    */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * Get the value of libelle
    */
    public function getLibelle()
    {
        return $this->libelle;
    }

    /**
    * Set the value of libelle
    *
    * @return  self
    */
    public function setLibelle($libelle)
    {
        $this->libelle = $libelle;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * Get the value of annonces
    */
    public function getAnnonces()
    {
        return $this->annonces;
    }

    /**
    * Set the value of annonces
    *
    * @return  self
    */
    public function setAnnonces($annonces)
    {
        $this->annonces = $annonces;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * Get the value of agents
    */
    public function getAgents()
    {
        return $this->agents;
    }

    /**
    * Set the value of agents
    *
    * @return  self
    */
    public function setAgents($agents)
    {
        $this->agents = $agents;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * Get the value of geometres
    */
    public function getGeometres()
    {
        return $this->geometres;
    }

    /**
    * Set the value of geometres
    *
    * @return  self
    */
    public function setGeometres($geometres)
    {
        $this->geometres = $geometres;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * Get the value of notaires
    */
    public function getNotaires()
    {
        return $this->notaires;
    }

    /**
    * Set the value of notaires
    *
    * @return  self
    */
    public function setNotaires($notaires)
    {
        $this->notaires = $notaires;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of createdAt
    */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
    * Set the value of createdAt
    *
    * @return  self
    */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Here is the query

```
public function geoPost()
{
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('p', 'u')
        ->from('App\Entities\Post', 'p')
        ->innerJoin('p.user', 'u')
        ->where('u.profil = :profil')
        ->setParameter('profil', 'geometre')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    return $qb;
}
```

The table Post.php and User.php are not linked to Villes.php

Answer (score 0):

Add to .env

```
DOCTRINE_PROXY_AUTOGENERATE=true
```

This will auto generate doctrine proxies.
If you want to do it manually you can use command:

```
php artisan doctrine:generate:proxies
```